# Limit left join

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to delete posts of post type using left join but i get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1'

Code:

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare("DELETE posts,pt,pm
        FROM wp_posts posts
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships pt ON ( pt.object_id = posts.ID AND pt.term_taxonomy_id = %d)
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = posts.ID
        WHERE posts.post_type = %s
        LIMIT %d
        ",
        456,
        'listing',
        1
    ) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LIMIT directly with a DELETE query, it's invalid syntax. I suggest you get the query working in a tool such as MySQL Workbench to ensure your syntax is correct first then you can migrate it to your WordPress code.